# c# Bitmap region is already locked, even after disposing the graphics objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

I'm new to C# and been trying to merge two images with the code below. I'm getting the bitmap region is locked exception and sometimes "the object is in use elsewhere".
I've tried to pass the clone of bitmaps and even return the `outputImage` as clone but then also the problem is same. I studied about `bitmap.LockBits` and `bitmap.Unlockbits` but I guess I was not able to use that properly. Please help me out.

This is how I'm using the function:

```cs
finalImage = MergeImagesSideways((Bitmap)imageCam1.Clone(), (Bitmap)imageCam2.Clone());
```

I would like to tell you that `imageCam1` and `imageCam2` are both made by a similar function that merges images upside down.

```cs
public Bitmap MergeImagesSideways(Image firstImage, Image secondImage)
{
    if (firstImage == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage");
    }

    if (secondImage == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage");
    }

    int outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width + secondImage.Width;

    int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height > secondImage.Height ? firstImage.Height : secondImage.Height;

    Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size),
            new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Rectangle(new Point(firstImage.Width, 0), secondImage.Size),
            new Rectangle(new Point(), secondImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.Dispose();
    }

    return outputImage;
}
```

edit: Everyone asked me to show the function which merges images upside down. So here it is

```
    private void MergeImagesCam2()
        {
            mergeImagesThread2 = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                //bitmapsMerge2 is a list which stores the images to be 
                merged
                if (bitmapsMerge2.Count > 0)
                {

                    Bitmap bmp = bitmapsMerge2[0];
                    
                    for (int i = 1; i < bitmapsMerge2.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //merge two images is very similar to the above code, 
                       //the differece is above code merges images sidesways and this upon each other
                        bmp = MergeTwoImages((Bitmap)bmp, bitmapsMerge2[i]);
                    }
                    
                    pictureBox4.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                    {
                        pictureBox4.Image = bmp;
                    }));
                    
                    imageCam2 = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();                
                    bitmapsMerge2.Clear();

                    finalImage = MergeImagesSideways((Bitmap)imageCam1.Clone(), (Bitmap)imageCam2.Clone());
                    
                    pictureBox5.Image = (Bitmap)finalImage.Clone();
                    Console.WriteLine("task done");
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

                }
            });
            mergeImagesThread2.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Assign `(Bitmap)imageCam1.Clone()` and friend to a local variable before calling `MergeImagesSideways()` and remove `graphics.Dispose();` -- You need to mention what line of code causes the exception and show where `imageCam1` and `imageCam2` come from (these things often are returned in an event handler that handles an event raised in a different Tread).

Comment: You are neglecting to dispose the images resulting from `imageCam1.Clone()` and `imageCam2.Clone()`, and it looks like we would need to see the similar function that merges images upside down.

Comment: @jimi I get exception when I try to save that image on any button event and I have a c++ project added, whenever I send the image from c# to c++. I get the same exception

Comment: @GSerg I've added the part which you've mentioned ,maybe  this will make things more clear. I did not get it when you said "You are neglecting to dispose the images"

Comment: 1. Remove the threading, that will remove one source of faults. If you really need it, use `Task.Run` and ensure the called method is pure.  2. merging two images in a loop like that is very inefficient, better to merge all images at the same time. 3. Ensure all images are disposed after use. 4. I would remove all the `.Clone()` calls, it seems like an example of shotgun debugging.

Comment: This code needs to be re-written from the ground up.  You have objects declared elsewhere used who knows how and where, you try to invoke a Control for no reason and the other control is not invoked, which would cause an exception. Don't set Images to properties of Controls from Threads, it doesn't make sense. You **could** use *shared* Bitmap objects with a Thread, setting the Image property of PictureBoxes to these objects. In this case, you just need to `Invalidate()` a PictureBox to see the result. BUT, separate the processing of Bitmaps from the UI (and don't `Invoke()`).

Comment: @jimi Thanks for the help mann. Can you please give me an example for "You could use shared Bitmap objects with a Thread, setting the Image property of PictureBoxes to these objects".

Comment: Still not clear when and where is `MergeImagesCam2()` is called and where the Bitmaps (those in `bitmapsMerge2[]` and `imageCam1`) it tries to handle come from or whether these Bitmaps are also concurrently set by other Threads. -- What is the purpose of these procedures? To show images coming from a device stream of sort (WebCam, security cameras) or prepare Bitmaps to be sent elsewhere? -- I don't see how you're passing a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to a C++ library.

Comment: @JonasH How cam I merge all images at same time ?

Comment: @Jimi looks like I've failed to explain my problem properly. Is there any way which you would like to suggest by which I can merge my images and don't get the images to be locked ?

Comment: @Nikunji Gaur Calculate the total size of all the bitmaps, create a bitmap at the final size and just use a graphics object to draw each bitmap at the correct position. That way each bitmap is drawn *once*.

Comment: Helloo Guys, I've found out the error and it's very silly, would you guys like to know it ? and what should I do in this case ? Just delete the question ?